# Angularjs Timeline Event Placement

Tags: html, css, angularjs, events, timeline

[image]I am using angularjs 1.5.0 and would like to make all of the events on my timeline appear on only one side. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. Are you talking about the view layout? This question seems overly vague. What have you tried?

Comment: I just added an image to the question. If I have that timeline on my page, I only want the "events" (the blocks of info coming off the timeline) to be on the right side of the "timeline-badge" (aka, the vertical line). I have tried added side= right attribute on the <timeline-node> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the **`timeline-inverted`** class from the html directive or remove it from the css file.